# How to use SASS with Polymer?

Tags: sass, components, polymer

I'm trying to use SASS with Polymer but I don't know how to have multiple outputs.

I'd like sass to compile each scss files in their own directory, I don't need a global css output...

Is there a solution to this issue ?
Thanks

Comment: We use compass in the polymer-project.org docs. If you're interested, take a look at how we've structured things: https://github.com/Polymer/docs/tree/master/sass

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use:

```
scss --watch ROOT_FOLDER:ROOT_FOLDER
```

example:

```
neciu$ mkdir dir1
neciu$ mkdir dir2
neciu$ touch dir1/1.scss
neciu$ touch dir2/2.scss
neciu$ scss --watch .:.
>>> Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
  write ./dir1/1.css
  write ./dir2/2.css
```